# asp.net display friends logged in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i want to display friends of a user who are currently logged in.

Comment: You need to elaborate Who is a "Friend". Where is this data stored and How do you want to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the [MembershipProvider.GetAllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getallusers.aspx) Method, to get a [MembershipUserCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.aspx) of all registered users in the application.

Then filter that collection on the property [IsOnline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isonline.aspx) of the [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) objects in this collection. ([EG with LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2009/02/21/displaying-online-users-using-linq-to-entities.aspx))

Comment: thnx Caspar... but i also  want to filter the users by their userid... like i have a list of userids (1,2,3,4,5,6,7..so on.. i want to check which of these users are online...